# Recursively count items in a multidimensional array in generic and idiomatic Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, multidimensional-array, functional-programming

I have a multi-dimensional array and I need a count of all of the items within all of the arrays, excluding container arrays themselves from the count.

What would be the most generic and idiomatic solution in Swift? I'm guessing it's going to be something functional (a `reduce()` operation?), but not sure on the best overall approach.

The obvious non-functional approach would be to simply iterate over the array and tally up the number of items.

Answer (score 3):

With the latest Swift 2.0 beta 6 you can use `flatten()`

```
let array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
array.flatten().count
```

EDIT: Just tested it: Lazy is not needed, the values are never evaluated, it just calculates `endIndex` - `startIndex` of every subcollection.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following :

```
let array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]

let countOfAll = array.map { (nested) -> Int in
    return nested.count
}.reduce(0, combine: +) // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 2 you can use `flatMap`.

```
var anArray = [[1,0,0], ["asdf","df","lef"], [0,0,1]]
var flatArray = anArray.flatMap { $0 }

print(flatArray.count) // 9
```

Comment: I just tested this, `flatMap` evaluates all of the sequences and creates a new one, `flatMap` can't be lazy..